# Pulling all rows from database then displaying them to a table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

Ok I have been searching for a day and a half with no luck. I have a simple Microsoft SQL database and I want to pull two rows from then display it in a view. What I have tried so far was

```
 public IEnumerable<Char> FindAllUsers()
        {
            var t = db.Users.SelectMany(c => c.FirstName).ToList();

            List<Char> list = t;

            return list;

        }
```

I have also tried

```
IEnumerable<User> name = db.Users
                         .Select(FirstName => FirstName)
                         .ToList();
            return name;

List<User> name = db.Users
                         .Select(FirstName => FirstName)
                         .ToList();
```

With no luck. I feel that I am not going about this the right way. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting? Can we see your view code?

Comment: What are you looking for? In one case you have `IEnumerable<Char>` and in others you have `IEnumerable<User>`

Comment: So far the error that I have been getting was "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Models.User]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Models.Project]'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
 var allUser= (from u in db.Users select u);
```

Answer (score 1):

Building up on Murali's answer, if you just want the names:

```
var allUserNames = (from u in db.Users select u.FirstName);
```